Setting a hosting site in a firebase project
I am facing some weird problem with setting a hosting site in a firebase project.
Here is the situation.
I want to use this name as a hosting site in my firebase project:
https://worldwonders.webapp.com/

But if I try to set it up, I get this message:
Site ID is unavailable. Available: worldwonders-9709b

At this point all is clear since I am already using the URL:
https://worldwonders.webapp.com/

inside another firebase project.
From now on things get less clear. I go to my other project and remove the site using worldwonders.webapp.com. It therefore becomes available for use.
The problem is that when I come back to my original project to set the hosting site the way I want, I still get the same kind of message as before, though the URL has been freed. What am I missing ? Or what do I need to do to keep using the URL below ? (that I was using up to now)
https://worldwonders.webapp.com/


First thing I'd do is give it time. Only Google knows how long it takes changes to propagate through the various systems

The worldwonders in https://worldwonders.web.app/ (which is what I assume you meant) is the project ID of the project you're hosting on Firebase Hosting. There is no to get a different subdomain URL for a project than the project ID.
See the documentation on deleting a project, which says:

You can't reuse the project ID of a deleted project.

So the project's name/ID never becomes available for re-use. Since the subdomain in Firebase Hosting is based on the project ID, you won't be able to get that same name either.
The common solution is to buy a custom domain and associate that with the project in Firebase Hosting, so that you fully own the domain that you advertise to your users.
